# How to Insert Multiple Data Into a Pivot Table Related to Other Tables with PHP and MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, foreach, foreign-keys

I have an application where I can create posts from the back office with PHP and MySQL.

Currently, I can only add one category for each post.

However, I would like to be able to add more than one category for each post.

To implement this functionality, I have to do several tasks on the database side and on the code side.

**1. Regarding the database side:**

In my database, I have 2 tables `posts` and `categories`.

So, I create a pivot table called `postcategories`, where I added 3 columns: post_categories_id which is the primary ket, post_id and cat_id which are the foreign keys I would like to join with the 2 other tables: `posts` and `categories`.

[image]

[image]

**2. On the code side:**

I have to loop through the categories coming from the form with a `foreach` loop and use `INSERT` SQL query.

To do this, I changed my code:

- I added the square brackets `[]` to the value of the `name` attribute named `post_category` in the `select` tag in the form and added the `multiple` attribute.

````
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="category">Categories</label>
    <select name="post_category[]" id="post_category" multiple>```

<?php

    $query = "SELECT * FROM categories";
    $select_categories = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select_categories)) {
        $cat_id    = escape($row['cat_id']);
        $cat_title = escape($row['cat_title']);
        echo "<option value='{$cat_id}'>{$cat_title}</option>";
    }
?>

    </select>
</div>
````

Now, I can select several categories in the back office in the `add_post.php` page.

[image]

- Then, I should create a `foreach` loop where I will be looping through the categories coming from the form.

```
if(!empty($_POST['post_category'])) {
    foreach($_POST['post_category'] as $list) {
    }
}
```

Can you guys correct this code if it requires any correction?

- Then, inside this foreach loop, I should insert these categories into a **pivot table** (which is `postcategories` in this case) and associate them with that current `post_id` (from the `posts` table).

Here, I'm not sure should I use the `categories` and the `cat_id` table as well?
If so, how should I use it?

At this point, my code looks like this:

```
if(!empty($_POST['post_category'])) {
    foreach($_POST['post_category'] as $list) {

        $query = "INSERT INTO posts
                            (post_category_id, post_title, post_author,             
                            post_date, post_image, post_content, 
                            post_tags, post_status) ";
        $query .= "VALUES({$list}, '{$post_title}', '{$post_author}', 
                            now(), '{$post_image}', '{$post_content}', 
                            '{$post_tags}', '{$post_status}') ";
        $create_post_query = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
        confirmQuery($create_post_query);
            $the_post_id = mysqli_insert_id($connection);
    }
}
```

I know, I'm not using neither the pivot table `postcategories` and neither the `categories` table in my code above.

It is just because, I'm not able to do it and I need help on this code logic.

Indeed, the pivot table in my case is `postcategories` and it has only 3 columns: `post_categories_id`, `post_id` and `cat_id`.

However, in my form in `add_post.php`, I have 7 fields.

=> So, I don't know how to insert those 7 values into the pivot table and how to associate them with that current `post_id`?

Here is my complete code in `add_post.php`:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['create_post'])){

    $post_title       = escape($_POST['post_title']);
    $post_author      = escape($_POST['post_author']);
    $post_category_id = $_POST['post_category'];
    $post_status      = escape($_POST['post_status']);

    $post_image       = $_FILES['image'] ['name'];
    $post_image_temp  = $_FILES['image'] ['tmp_name'];

    $post_tags        = escape($_POST['post_tags']);
    $post_content     = escape($_POST['post_content']);
    $post_date        = escape(date('d-m-y'));

    move_uploaded_file($post_image_temp, "../assets/img/blog/$post_image");

    if(!empty($_POST['post_category'])) {
        foreach($_POST['post_category'] as $list) {

            $query = "INSERT INTO posts
                            (post_category_id, post_title, post_author, 
                            post_date, post_image, post_content, 
                            post_tags, post_status) ";
            $query .= "VALUES({$list}, '{$post_title}', '{$post_author}',
                                now(), '{$post_image}', 
                                '{$post_content}', '{$post_tags}', 
                                '{$post_status}') ";
            $create_post_query = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
            confirmQuery($create_post_query);
            $the_post_id = mysqli_insert_id($connection);
        }
    }
    
    echo "<h4 class='bg-success text-center'>Post Created: <a href='../post.php?p_id={$the_post_id}'>View Post</a> or <a href='posts.php'>View All Posts</a></h4>";
}
?>
    
    <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="title">Post Title</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="post_title">
    </div>
    
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="category">Categories</label>
        <select name="post_category[]" id="post_category" multiple>
    
    <?php    
    $query = "SELECT * FROM categories";
    $select_categories = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
    
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select_categories)) {
        $cat_id    = escape($row['cat_id']);    
        $cat_title = escape($row['cat_title']);
        echo "<option value='{$cat_id}'>{$cat_title}</option>";
    }
    ?>
    
        </select>
    </div>
        
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="title">Post Author</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="post_author">
    </div>
    
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="post_status">Post Status</label>
        <select name="post_status" id="post_status">
            <option value="Draft">Post Status</option>
            <option value="Published">Published</option>
            <option value="Draft">Draft</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="post_image">Post Image</label>
        <input type="file" name="image">
    </div>
    
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="post_tags">Post Tags</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="post_tags">
    </div>
    
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="summernote">Post Content</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" name="post_content" id="summernote" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
    </div>
    
    <div class="form-group">
        <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="create_post" value="Publish Post">
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Your script is open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174). 
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187)
You should always use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) 
in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's instead of concatenating user provided values into the query. Never trust ANY user input!
This will also remove the unescaped character issue like a `'` in a text string like `O'Neal'.

Comment: @RiggsFolly: I wrote the code you provided to me and there is a typo, `you wrote $stmt = $connections->prepare($query);` with a `s` instead of `$stmt = $connection->prepare($query);`. However, I still get this error below

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'CURDATE(), post_image, post_content, post_tags, pos...' at line 2 in C:\xampp\htdocs\projects\online-projects\clique-digitale-php\admin\includes\add_post.php:26

Comment: Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\projects\online-projects\clique-digitale-php\admin\includes\add_post.php(26): mysqli->prepare('INSERT INTO pos...') #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\projects\online-projects\clique-digitale-php\admin\posts.php(28): include('C:\\xampp\\htdocs...') #2 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\projects\online-projects\clique-digitale-php\admin\includes\add_post.php on line 26

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments. Please delete & flag obsolete comments. [Help] Debug questions require a [mre].

Answer (score 1):

First `post_category_id` no longer belongs in the `posts` table

Then all you need to do is clean up the SQL Injection issues and add a loop to process the possible multiple categories selected by the user

```
if(isset($_POST['create_post'])){

    // NOTE this is bad idea, what if 2 people have an image with the same name
    move_uploaded_file($post_image_temp, 
                        "../assets/img/blog/" . $_FILES['image']['name']
                    );

    if(!empty($_POST['post_category'])) {
        $query = "INSERT INTO posts
                        (post_title, post_author, post_date, 
                        post_image, post_content, post_tags, post_status)
                    VALUES(?,?,CURDATE(),?,?,?,?)";

        $stmt = $connection->prepare($query);
        $stmt->bind_param('ssssss',
                            $_POST['post_title'],
                            $_POST['post_author'],
                            $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], // bad idea see above
                            $_POST['post_content'],
                            $_POST['post_tags'],
                            $_POST['post_status']);
        if ( $stmt->execute() ) {
            $the_post_id = $connection->insert_id;
        }

        // now loop over the categories selected on the form
        // and create the cross reference table records

        // prepare query once run it multiple times with different data
        // saves server round trips

        $sql = 'INSERT INTO postcategories (post_id, cat_id) VALUES(?,?)';
        $stmt = $connection->prepare($sql);

        foreach( $_POST['post_category'] as $cat_id){
            $stmt->bind_param('ii', $the_post_id, $cat_id);
            $stmt->execute();            
        }
    }
```

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252866/discussion-on-answer-by-riggsfolly-how-to-insert-multiple-data-into-a-pivot-tabl); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.